# How to determine jQuery UI tab element before initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I want to have jQuery function that determines passed element is tab content, Is this possible to find it before the tab is initialized and i dont want any additional class or attribute to be added to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't initialized it as tab widget using `tab()` method, there is no way to find out whether it is going to be a tab widget in the future.

You can check for the matching HTML structure, for example say an `<a>` element with a local `href` having an `<li>` as it's parent - But it could be the markup for a menu, or a sortable list, or anything else with some CSS magic. The computer can not read your mind (*as of now, as per my knowlege*).

So unless you add an attribute that identifies the elements which are going to be initialized as tabs, there is no way to find out what will we tabs in **future**